# How to do UNIX crypt(3) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, password-encryption, crypt, node-ffi

Is there a way to do UNIX crypt(3) in javascript (in node.js, specifically)?

crypt(3) uses DES, I guess it can done by openssl, but how to access openssl from javascript?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I found how to do it with [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi):

```
var ffi = require('node-ffi');

var libcrypt = ffi.Library('libcrypt', {
  'crypt': ['string', ['string', 'string']]
});

console.log(libcrypt.crypt('aa', 'bb'));
```

Comment: have you looked at this? http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: @ryanc1256: I checked and didn't find anything that does what crypt(3) does.

Comment: DES cipher is present in crypto. See crypto.getCiphers().